# how to use latest castle windsor wcf integration facility

Tags: wcf, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container, castle

I'm playing around with Castle WCF integration facility because I want to integrate my WCF services with windsor IOC.

The issue I'm facing is that I can't set IKernel for DefaultServiceHostFactory.

I setup the container:

```
container = new WindsorContainer().AddFacility<WcfFacility>();
        container.Register(Component.For<DefaultServiceHostFactory>());
        container.Register(Component.For<IFoo>().ImplementedBy<Foo>());
```

Then I setup the SVC file:

```
<%@ ServiceHost 
Language="C#" 
Debug="true" 
Service="Foo" 
Factory="Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.DefaultServiceHostFactory, Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration"%>
```

When WCF tries to instantiate DefaultServiceHostFactory it says kernell is null and recommends using DefaultServiceHostFactory.RegisterContainer(IKernel kernel) method. However this method is not available in latest version of WCF facility.

Any help appriceated!

Thanks

Comment: How about putting your solution as an answer and marking it as such?  That way the question will not remain on the unanswered list.

Comment: That would be very useful as I am also trying to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out, I was deploying the application to windows Azure and I used the web role startup for container registration (WRONG!) once I putted the container setup into Global.asax file it started working for IIS and Azure emulator as well.